How can I create temporary tables and run queries from Postgres-nio client
I am trying to run some complex queries where I need to create a temporary table to store and summarise data and the fetch the summary results.
I am using Postgres-nio Swift client but can't seem to create temporary tables using the following approach.
    let results = try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self, returning: ChangeData.self) { taskGroup in
        taskGroup.addTask {
           await client.run() 
        }
    
        try await client.query("CREATE TEMP TABLE ABC (....)")
        
        try await client.query("INSERT INTO ABC (....) SELECT ... FROM XYZ")
        try await client.query("INSERT INTO ABC (....) SELECT ... FROM GHI")
        
        try await client.query("SELECT * FROM ABC")
    
        taskGroup.cancelAll()
                
        return storeChangeDate
    }

However I am always getting an error indicating the temp table is not found.
Originally I was using a FUNCTION but I want to avoid that where possible to retain as much logic in the client application rather than having to update some database functions with updates to the application.  This is primarily for reporting purposes.
Strangely it seems that if I call a prepared statement to call a Postgres function and after doing that use the following calls I don't get any errors about missing temporary tables.  But if I remove the first call to the function then I am always getting errors because the temporary tables are not found when performing the insert function.
What am I missing here ?
EDIT:
Ok so it seems that Postgres-nio is using a connection pool and therefor doesn't always use the same connection for consecutive queries.
My workaround is to allow a maximum of only 1 connection for the client - therefor ensuring that the same Postgres 'session' is being used.
This seems to work but it would be better if there was a more definitive way of doing this - perhaps somehow requesting a specific connection from the PostgresClient !??

Temporary tables only exist in the session that creates them. You look to be creating multiple sessions and the subsequent sessions don't see the temp table created in the first session.

@AdrianKlaver - I am not clear on how Postgres-nio client relates to a 'Postgres' session.  In the example above the PostgresClient 'client' is the same one and is active with the client.run() call during the consecutive calls to client.query().
If each client.query() is a separate session then how does one run these statements in the same session ?

Why do you need it? ‘complex’ is just an opinion. Besides that, a CTE can work like a temp table.

@FrankHeikens - what is a CTE ?

Common Table Expression: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Ah thanks - I will look into that but I need to be able to set certain properties in the temporary tables with update statements. In any event I found the solution that works for the temp tables.

it seems the answer I was looking for is this
let results = try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self, returning: ChangeData.self) { taskGroup in
        taskGroup.addTask {
           await client.run() 
        }

        try await conn.withConnection { conn in 
    
           try await conn.query("CREATE TEMP TABLE ABC (....)", logger:...)
        
           try await conn.query("INSERT INTO ABC (....) SELECT ... FROM XYZ", logger:...)
           try await conn.query("INSERT INTO ABC (....) SELECT ... FROM GHI", logger:...)
        
           try await conn.query("SELECT * FROM ABC")

        }
    
        taskGroup.cancelAll()
                
        return storeChangeDate
    }

However be sure to include the logger: parameter or an older API will be used that doesn't support PostgresQuery.
